# E4 contribute to a perspective

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have a perspective that is defined in a plugin.xml. Is it possible to contribute with a fragment containing a part sash and some parts to that perspective ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using E4 with compatibility layer: you cannot extend an E3 perspective with additional elements using E4 fragments. E3 compat layer works on top of E4, i.e. when the E4 fragments are processed, the E3 perspective is not yet available.

You could achieve this programmatically, but that (E3 and E4 mix) is not supported (at least not up to Eclipse Oxygen as of today).